# Creating class cluster (with factory methods) in Swift: "cannot convert return expression of type 'Subclass?' to return type 'Self?'"

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a class cluster--when I create as instance of `Class` from JSON, I want to be able to return a subclass of `Class`. However I can't seem to make the types work out.

Seems the instance of `Subclass` should be convertable to `Class`. Isn't `Class` of type `Self` here?

Help.

```
protocol JSONSerializable
{
    static func withJSONRepresentation( json:Any? ) -> Self?
}

class Class : JSONSerializable
{
    static func withJSONRepresentation( json:Any? ) -> Self?
    {
        return Subclass( jsonRepresentation: json )
    }
    init?( jsonRepresentation:Any? )
    {
        // init instance here
    }
}

class Subclass : Class
{
    override init?( jsonRepresentation:Any? )
    {
        // init instance here
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me why the return type is `Self?`. For a class cluster the return type would be the "umbrella class" (e.g. `Class`), but the returned values are instances of some subclass.

Comment: It's because of the conformance to _JSONSerializable_. calling _Class.withJSONRepresentation()_ should return a subclass of _Class_

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after? I am using `self.init` in the return, which therefore needs a `required init`.

```
protocol JSONSerializable
{
    static func withJSONRepresentation( json:Any? ) -> Self?
}

class Class : JSONSerializable
{
    static func withJSONRepresentation( json:Any? ) -> Self?
    {
        return self.init( jsonRepresentation: json )
    }
    required init( jsonRepresentation:Any? )
    {
    }
}

class Subclass : Class
{
    required init( jsonRepresentation:Any? )
    {
        super.init(jsonRepresentation: jsonRepresentation)
    }
}

print(Class.withJSONRepresentation(nil))      // -> Class
print(Subclass.withJSONRepresentation(nil))   // -> Subclass
```

EDIT:

An alternative is to return a JSONSerializable (or Class) instance, but then depending on your needs, you may have to downcast to the required type.

The problem with your existing code is the compiler cannot guarantee you will meet your promise of returning an instance of `Self`. For example, when calling `Subclass.withJSONRepresentation`, your code could return an instance of `Class` (or anything else), which breaks the promise. Actually this is the crux of the matter - with your current code, if the json means it needs to return a `Class`, you would have to call it on the `Class` static func, whereas if it should return a `Subclass`, you would have to call it on the `Subclass` static func. "Self" does not include subclasses, so if called on the `Class` static func, it must only ever return a `Class` instance, not a subclass.

```
protocol JSONSerializable
{
    static func withJSONRepresentation( json:Any? ) -> JSONSerializable?
}

class Class : JSONSerializable
{
    static func withJSONRepresentation( json:Any? ) -> JSONSerializable?
    {
        return Subclass( jsonRepresentation: json )
    }
    init?( jsonRepresentation:Any? )
    {
        // init instance here
    }
}

class Subclass : Class
{
}

print(Class.withJSONRepresentation(nil))
```

Comment: not quite--the value of `json` should determine the subclass to be initialized.

Comment: There is an alternative, but it's a bit uglier. I will update my answer.

Comment: Ok..that's the problem: "'Self' does not include subclasses". That makes no sense to me. Subclasses of _Self_ always conform to _Self_, don't they?.

Comment: They do conform, but they're not the same. For example with constructors, Class() must always return an instance of only Class, and Subclass() must always return an instance of Subclass. For some reason "Self" (upper-case S) is not in the Swift grammar doco.

Comment: Sure.. Perhaps there's some underlying reason. But as far as the caller is concerned, they're getting a _Class_ instance.